# Reliable source of RPMs for CentOS?

Tags: security, package-management, rpm

I know I can use Redhat and CentOS rpms on my CentOS 6.7/6.8 systems.

However, I feel I can only trust rpms that come from the redhat and centos web sites, or other reliable/known-to-me sites.

Now I need to install tcl, and I am not finding it.

What is the normal, reasonably secure way to find rpms, for tcl and other business apps?

(For installing Redis, I switched to building from source, because I went crazy chasing rpms)

Comment: Better you bought RHEL from RedHat and got all rpm from Redhat Network.I knew how to get tcl rpm package.But I didnt know secure or unsecure rpm package.I used Centos/SL for testing not Critical Server.

Answer (score 1):

tcl is present on the CentOS repo.

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/

[image: tcl rpms]